# AttributeType::String is NULL in my database

Tags: plugin-development, database, models, records, attribute

I have create a plugin to save information from my form in the front-end.

I can create a row with some data.

Email and Number type work well but String is NULL

Have you any idea ?

### my controller

```
public function actionSaveInscription()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();

    if ($id = craft()->request->getPost('inscriptionId')) {
       $model = craft()->inscriptionCommunautes->getInscriptionById($id);
    } else {
        $model = craft()->inscriptionCommunautes->newInscription($id);
    }

    $attributes = craft()->request->getPost('inscription');

    $model->setAttributes($attributes);

    if (craft()->inscriptionCommunautes->saveInscription($model)) {
        craft()->userSession->setNotice(Craft::t('Inscription saved.'));
        $model->getAttribute('id')));
    }
}
```

### My Service (saveAction)

```
public function saveInscription(InscriptionCommunautes_InscriptionModel &$model)
{
    if ($id = $model->getAttribute('id')) {
        if (null === ($record = $this->inscriptionRecord->findByPk($id))) {
            throw new Exception(Craft::t('Can\'t find inscription with ID "{id}"', array('id' => $id)));
        }
    } else {
        $record = $this->inscriptionRecord->create();
    }
        $record->setAttributes($model->getAttributes());
    if ($record->save()) {
        $model->setAttribute('id', $record->getAttribute('id'));
        return true;
    } else {
        $model->addErrors($record->getErrors());
        return false;
    }
}
```

### My Model

```
protected function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'id' => AttributeType::Number,
        'communaute' => AttributeType::String,
        'nom' => AttributeType::String,
        'courriel' => AttributeType::Email,
        'telephone' => AttributeType::String,
        'entraineurs' => AttributeType::Number,
        'accompagnateurs' => AttributeType::Number,
        'athletes' => AttributeType::Number,
    );
}
```

### My Record

```
public function getTableName()
{
    return 'CustomPlugin_Inscriptions';
}

protected function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'communaute' => AttributeType::String,
        'nom' => AttributeType::String,
        'courriel' => AttributeType::Email,
        'telephone' => AttributeType::String,
        'entraineurs' => AttributeType::Number,
        'accompagnateurs' => AttributeType::Number,
        'athletes' => AttributeType::Number,
    );
}

public function defineIndexes()
{
    return array(

    );
}

public function create()
{
    $class = get_class($this);
    $record = new $class();

    return $record;
}
```

### Craft::dd($model);

```
 Craft\InscriptionCommunautes_InscriptionModel#1
(
    [*:classSuffix] => 'Model'
    [*:strictAttributes] => true
    [Craft\BaseModel:_classHandle] => null
    [Craft\BaseModel:_attributeConfigs] => array
    (
        'id' => array
        (
            'maxLength' => 11
            'min' => -2147483648
            'max' => 2147483647
            'decimals' => 0
            'type' => 'number'
            'unsigned' => false
            'length' => 10
            'column' => 'integer'
        )
        'communaute' => array
        (
            'type' => 'string'
        )
        'nom' => array
        (
            'type' => 'string'
        )
        'courriel' => array
        (
            'maxLength' => 255
            'minLength' => 5
            'column' => 'varchar'
            'type' => 'email'
        )
        'telephone' => array
        (
            'type' => 'string'
        )
        'entraineurs' => array
        (
            'maxLength' => 11
            'min' => -2147483648
            'max' => 2147483647
            'decimals' => 0
            'type' => 'number'
            'unsigned' => false
            'length' => 10
            'column' => 'integer'
        )
        'accompagnateurs' => array
        (
            'maxLength' => 11
            'min' => -2147483648
            'max' => 2147483647
            'decimals' => 0
            'type' => 'number'
            'unsigned' => false
            'length' => 10
            'column' => 'integer'
        )
        'athletes' => array
        (
            'maxLength' => 11
            'min' => -2147483648
            'max' => 2147483647
            'decimals' => 0
            'type' => 'number'
            'unsigned' => false
            'length' => 10
            'column' => 'integer'
        )
    )
    [Craft\BaseModel:_attributes] => array
    (
        'communaute' => 'communaute'
        'nom' => 'nom'
        'courriel' => 'courriel@domaine.com'
        'telephone' => '1231231212'
        'entraineurs' => '1'
        'accompagnateurs' => '2'
        'athletes' => '3'
    )
    [Craft\BaseModel:_extraAttributeNames] => null
    [CModel:_errors] => array()
    [CModel:_validators] => null
    [CModel:_scenario] => ''
    [CComponent:_e] => null
    [CComponent:_m] => null
)
```

### Craft::dd($model->getAttributes());

```
array
(
    'id' => null
    'communaute' => 'comm'
    'nom' => 'name'
    'courriel' => 'email@domaine.com'
    'telephone' => '1231231231'
    'entraineurs' => '1'
    'accompagnateurs' => '2'
    'athletes' => '3'
)
```

### Database Structure Generated

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `craft_InscriptionCommunautes_Inscriptions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `communaute` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `courriel` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `entraineurs` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accompagnateurs` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `athletes` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateUpdated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `uid` char(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Comment: Can you post some relevant code in the original question? Hard to tell what's going on without some context.

Comment: Does your record have similar attributes? If you `Craft::dd($record)` right before you save it in your server are all of the attribute values setup properly?

Comment: what is the dd function ?

Comment: Dump and die (http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference//Craft#dd-detail). Will dump a variable's contents to the screen and end the request.

Comment: no idea anyone ?


the string array is tiny in comparison with email :
'nom' => array
(
    'type' => 'string'
)
'courriel' => array
(
    'maxLength' => 255
    'minLength' => 5
    'column' => 'varchar'
    'type' => 'email'
)

Comment: Sorry... `Craft::dd($model->getContent());` instead of just `$model`.

Comment: it give me an error 
Craft\InscriptionCommunautes_InscriptionModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getContent". 

with a stack trace

Comment: I'll get it right eventually... `Craft::dd($model->getAttributes());`

Comment: What about `Craft::dd($record->getAttributes());` right before you call `$record->save()` in your service?

Comment: array  
(  
    'id' => null  
    'communaute' => 'comm'  
    'nom' => 'name'  
    'courriel' => 'email@domaine.com'  
    'telephone' => '1231231231'  
    'entraineurs' => '1'  
    'accompagnateurs' => '2'  
    'athletes' => '3'  
)

Comment: I'm stumped... everything looks like it should work. If you look at the `courriel` column in the database, what data type is it set to?  `varchar(255)`?

Comment: it's really weird. i have added the database export structure

Comment: i have try Mixed and Name type. with mixed, its the same thing but with Name it finally work

Comment: I'm new to Craft development but I found that `AttributeType::String` does not perform any validation and therefore is considered unsafe to store in your db. Try using `AttributeType::Name` to validate against a string. [Here is my thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/save-contact-form-data-to-database/8887?noredirect=1#comment10466_8887) so you can see what I was finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AttributeType::Name` instead, this will undergo validation

Comment: What.  This seems like a workaround for something broken in Craft.